# postgresql: how to avoid receiving boolen answer from select query

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to do some calculations in the select statement and my code was

```
SELECT DATE (TIME), 
round(100.0 * COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE STATUS LIKE '404%') / COUNT(log.STATUS), 2) AS errors
FROM log
GROUP BY DATE (TIME)
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

and the output was fine

`date      | errors 
-----------+-------
2016-07-17 |   2.26
2016-07-19 |   0.78
2016-07-24 |   0.78
2016-07-06 |   0.77`

but when I try to change the code to this sentence

```
SELECT DATE (TIME), 
(100.0 * COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE STATUS LIKE '404%') / COUNT(log.STATUS) > 1) AS errors
FROM log
GROUP BY DATE (TIME)
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```

I receive a Boolean output and i want the output to show only the first row

`date    | errors 
------------+--------
 2016-07-17 | t
 2016-07-02 | f
 2016-07-03 | f
 2016-07-04 | f`

Comment: The `>` in your second query is a comparison operator.  So it will return either true or false.  If you want only the first line, add a LIMIT clause (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a `WHERE` clause over and above your result to get the `> 1` records.

```
SELECT "Date"
    ,errors
FROM (
    SELECT DATE (TIME) AS "Date"
        ,round(100.0 * COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE STATUS LIKE '404%') 
        / COUNT(log.STATUS), 2) AS errors
    FROM log
    GROUP BY DATE (TIME)
    ) a
WHERE a.errors > 1
ORDER BY errors DESC;
```